# Force as a Function of Position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces

If given a velocity as a function of position, is force as a function of position just it's derivative times the mass? I'm given the following and I am not sure my above logic is correct:

The speed of a particle with mass $m$ varies with distance $x$ as 
$$v\left(x\right)=ax^{-n}$$
You should assume $v\left(x=0\right)=0$ at time $t=0$.

Find Force as a Function of Position

So would $F(x)=m\frac{dv\left(x\right)}{dx}$?

Comment: $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot v$

Comment: A simple dimensions check would have shows your relation for force is incorrect. $F = [kg/m/s^2]$, $m\frac{dv}{dx} = [kg/s]$, this shows you are missing a factor with dimension $[m/s]$, which corresponds coincidentally to a velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please correct your logic

Force  is defined as "rate of change of momentum" and its direction is the direction of  $d\mathbf{p}/dt$ which is a vector as $\mathbf{p}$ is a vector. Momentum ($\mathbf{p}$) is mass times the velocity and your velocity is a function of $x$.

If momentum is a function of position, as in your case,  its rate of change will involve the rate of change of position with time i.e. one can write it as:

$$
F = m \frac{dv}{dt} = m \frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}= m v \frac{dv}{dx} 
$$
In your case as  as $v= a. x^{-n}$  ;

$$
dv/dx= a. d/dx(x^{-n})
      =a(-n).x^{-n+1}
      =-a.n.x^{(1-n)}
$$

therefore:

$$
F= m.a.{-n} v. x^{(1-n)} =-m.a.n.a.x^-n.x^{1-n} =- m.a^2. n.(x^ {(1-2n)})
$$

so you get a force which is a function of $x$.
so your conclusion that force will be mass times $dx/dt$ is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

dont make things so complicated: m(dv/dt)=F...then multiple both sides by v(dt), we get mv(dv)=Fv(dt)...because vdt=dx....then mv(dv)=F(x^0)(dx)...intergrate...and you find  K.E.=P.E., or force as a function of position is potential energy.